# Notepad++ Regex - Issue with ^ anchor and repeating patterns

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

When one tries to remove some characters from the start of a line and the anchored pattern can be found again after the first replace, it will be removed again.

For a very simple example given the input `012345`, search pattern `^.` and empty replacement, Notepad++ will remove the whole line when using *replace all*. This is most likely due to the case, that the cursor is still at the start of the line after the first replace and thus matches the `^` anchor again.

How can one ensure that only the actual first character is removed (in my case the expected output would be `12345`)?

You can see my workaround in my answer, but maybe there is another nice trick to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

One can match the rest of the line, capture the match into a group and then use this group as replacement. The pattern in the question could be adjusted to `^.(.*)` and be replaced by `$1`.

This will force the cursor to move forward in the string, so the `^` anchor can't match again.

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround could be finding:

```
^.(.)?
```

and replacing it with:

```
\1
```

I'm sure this is a subject of a bug report but couldn't find it as of now. In N++:

- Anchors are buggy

> [image]

- By <kbd>Replace All</kbd> functionality, replacements are supposed to not be a subject to re-matching. But they are, when replacement strings are invisible / zero-length characters.

> [image]

Take care of them.