# Regex: How to remove everything before a colon on each line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have tried using this regex to remove everything before a colon, however, it removes recurrsively.

```
^[^:]+:\s*
```

The following needs to change from

```
afghanistan : Afghanistan
albania : Albania
algeria : Algeria
andorra : Andorra
angola : Angola
```

to

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Where do you use this (tool/language)? If notepad++ see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017426/notepad-regex-issue-with-anchor-and-repeating-patterns

Comment: Am using Brackets. The below answer by @Wiktor Stribiżew works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure you do not overflow across lines, you need to add `\r\n` to the negated character class and replace `\s` that can match line breaks with `\h` (horizontal whitespace pattern) (or `[ \t]` if `\h` is not supported).

So, you might use

```
^[^:\r\n]+:\h*
```

([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB6tGc/1)) or

```
^[^:\r\n]+:[ \t]*
```

to replace with an empty string ([another demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB6tGc/2)).

*In Notepad++*, you need to match the whole  line to get rid of the recursive behavior:

```
^[^:\r\n]+:\h*(.*)
```

Replace with `\1`. See [yet another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB6tGc/3).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a line (if not default, prepend with `(?m)` inline modifier)
- `[^:\r\n]+` - 1 or more chars other than `:`, CR and LF
- `:` -  a colon
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` or `$1` from the replacement pattern) capturing any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (up to the end of line).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "afghanistan : Afghanistan" | sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)/\2/'
```